# How to make sure activity is running (AdMob interstitial)

Tags: android, android-activity, admob, interstitial

I have implemented AdMob interstitial in my app the method works like this:

- I construct ads object in my activity. (Ads object has reference to the activity)
- In my ads object I check if interstitial was shown in last three
  minutes with timer, and if it hasn't been shown I show it through
  handler to that activity.
- If activity is stoped or destroyed I also stop my ads timer

Most of the time this scenario works correctly. But sometimes the ads show up one time even if the app is already exited.

Is there a way to check from my ads object if the activity is really running and it is the current activity running on the screen ?

Answer (score 0):

With the help of below code, you can get the top activity in android :

```
public static boolean isThisActivityOnTop(Context context,Class<?> activityClass){
    ActivityManager am = (ActivityManager) context
            .getSystemService(ACTIVITY_SERVICE);

    ActivityManager.RunningTaskInfo taskInfo = am.getRunningTasks(1)
            .get(0);

    String topActivityClass = taskInfo.baseActivity.getClassName();

    return topActivityClass.equalsIgnoreCase(activityClass.getName());
}
```

NB :  The code is not tested, please try it (debug).